# How do I download Docker if I uninstalled Docker using Explorer and not the default uninstaller?

Tags: windows, docker, installation

I can't install Docker. I **removed** all *dwords* and *qwords* in the **regit** of Windows. I also removed Docker from **Program Files** and from **ProgramData**. And when I try to run the Docker installation it says you already have **Docker version 3.0.0**. A new installation is not ***possible***. There is **no** Docker repair file on the internet. You always have to have Docker. The docker command in cmd doesn't work either. How can I install Docker?

I'm trying to delete all files named Docker and restart the computer over and over again. I assume that I will be able to use Docker again without any problems afterwards

Comment: It would be good if you can also upload some error messages (images or any format possible)